# Logistic regression using glm give strange predictions, only very small probabilities

Tags: logistic-regression

I want to regress a binary variable of 0 and 1 onto a continuous variable ranging from 0 to 120. So I fit `glm(y~x,family='binomial')` and make predictions using `predict(fit,newdata=x,type=c('response'))`, and plotting these gives

[image]

where the black dots are observations and red dots are predicted probabilities. I don't understand why the curve does not go down from 1 but only produce probabilities from 0 to 0.05, is there anything I have done wrong or is it just because there are too many 0 observations?

One more thing is that the predictor variable is a positive variable, so extending the axis to the left does not really give sensible predictions. Is there a way to resolve this?

Here's the summary table for observed responses:

```
> table(test_y)
test_y
   0    1 
9778  462
```

Comment: Can you add the result of `table(y)` so that readers can understand how unbalanced your data is?

Comment: Thanks for the advice!